# Adding Wave Trend Oscillator and MACD in one script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to combine Wave Trend Oscillator and MACD in one script, but encountering he following error -

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Script could not be translated
> from: ["SMA", "EMA"])|E| |B|sma_signal

My code is as follows -

```
//study(title="WaveTrend", shorttitle="WT")
n1 = input.int(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input.int(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")
 
ap = hlc3 
esa = ta.ema(ap, n1)
d = ta.ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ta.ema(ci, n2)
 
wt1 = tci
wt2 = ta.sma(wt1,4)

plot(0, color=gray)
plot(obLevel1, color=red)
plot(osLevel1, color=green)
plot(obLevel2, color=red, style=3)
plot(osLevel2, color=green, style=3)

plot(wt1, color=green)
plot(wt2, color=red, style=3)
plot(wt1-wt2, color=blue, style=area, transp=80)

//MACD
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mix of version 2, 4 and 5. Try upgrading all to v5.

This should work:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="WaveTrend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="WT_LB")
n1 = input.int(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input.int(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")
 
ap = hlc3 
esa = ta.ema(ap, n1)
d = ta.ema(math.abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ta.ema(ci, n2)
 
wt1 = tci
wt2 = ta.sma(wt1,4)

plot(0, color=color.gray)
plot(obLevel1, color=color.red)
plot(osLevel1, color=color.green)
plot(obLevel2, color=color.red, linewidth=3)
plot(osLevel2, color=color.green, linewidth=3)

color c_blue = color.new(color.blue, 80)
plot(wt1, color=color.green)
plot(wt2, color=color.red, linewidth=3)
plot(wt1-wt2, color=c_blue, style=plot.style_area)

//MACD
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```